# How to access google drive from HTML 5 in android

Tags: html5-video, google-drive-api

I have an HTML 5 which open the android Camera and takes a picture, I need this picture to be stored in Google drive and get back the unique URL (for google docs).  How can it be done ?

Answer (score 0):

The Drive quickstart sample for Android explains how to write an app that uses the device camera to take photos and then automatically uploads those photos to Drive:

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android

It is not exactly what you are asking for, but I think it is all you need to get started with it.